# Around Annotation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

I've the following programs. The around method is getting called but why not the main method? As far as i know around method gets executed before or after the method execution. Here around method getting called but why it's not printing the main method i.e.,getEmploy();.

```
@Configuration
public class App extends Thread{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.scan("com.inno.aop");
        context.refresh();
        EmployManager emp = (EmployManager) context.getBean("employManager");
        emp.getEmploy();
        context.close();
    }

}


@Service
public class EmployManager {

    public void getEmploy() {
        System.out.println("Here is your employ" );
    }
    public void getEmp() {
        System.out.println("Here is your emp" );
    }
}


@Aspect
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class EmployAspect {

     @Around("execution(* com.inno.aop.EmployManager.*(..))")
     public void logAround(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
         System.out.println("Around method getting called");
    }

}



Output:

Around method getting called
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-introduction-defn)

> Around advice: Advice that surrounds a join point such as a method
>   invocation. This is the most powerful kind of advice. Around advice
>   can perform custom behavior before and after the method invocation. It
>   is also responsible for choosing whether to proceed to the join point
>   or to shortcut the advised method execution by returning its own
>   return value or throwing an exception.

We need to use `ProceedingJoinPoint` with [@Around](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice) advice

`org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint`

> Around advice is declared by using the @Around annotation. The first
>   parameter of the advice method must be of type ProceedingJoinPoint.
>   Within the body of the advice, calling proceed() on the
>   ProceedingJoinPoint causes the underlying method to execute. The
>   proceed method can also pass in an Object[]. The values in the array
>   are used as the arguments to the method execution when it proceeds.

The code should be

```
 @Around("execution(* com.inno.aop.EmployManager.*(..))")
 public void logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
     System.out.println("Around method getting called");
     joinPoint.proceed();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Around aspect intercepts the call and you can decide whether to proceed to the real class or not. In this code snipped you just call `System.out.println` and do not run the real class's method...

You should call:

```
@Around(...)
public void logAround(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
   jointPoint.proceed();  // + handle exceptions if required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Within the method annotated with @Around, one need to call `joinPoint.proceed()`, then only the intercepted method will be called. Also,

1. make sure to extract the method arguments and pass that to `joinPoint.proceed(Object[] args)`.
2. Return the object returned by joinPoint.proceed, from your logAround() method, incase intercepted method is not a void.

```java
@Aspect
@Component
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class EmployAspect {

    @Around("execution(* com.inno.aop.EmployManager.*(..))")
    public void logAround(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        System.out.println("Around method getting called");
        joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```